# Removing duplicates from a large table with NULL columns that also need to be taken into account

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I am interested in removing duplicates from a very large table (40+ million records, 3+ GB in size), that also has to count NULL columns when determining duplicates.   5.5.56-MariaDB, tables are in InnoDB format.

The problem I'm running into is that some of the recommended methods will not work when it comes to NULL field comparison.    For example, I have a table that has about a dozen columns, many of which can contain NULL values, and I want NULLs treated as any other value, in that if a row has the same NULL values in the same columns, it's considered a dupe.

The technique below does NOT work:

```
create table tmp like mytable;
alter table tmp ADD UNIQUE INDEX(field1,field2, field3,...);
insert IGNORE into tmp (select * from mytable);
```

At this point, tmp should have all dupes removed, but NULL columns are ignored in the Unique index, so it doesn't work.  If it did work, then I could rename the tables, or truncate the original table and copy over (assuming I wanted to preserve a primary key in the original table).

What is the most efficient way of deleting dupes in large files when dealing with NULL columns that should also be taken into consideration?

Additional notes:   I have a field called "recno" that is Auto Increment that needs to be ignored.

Comment: Will you end up with less than half as many rows?  Or more?  The focus so far has been on the former.  The latter leads to `DELETEing` dups.

Comment: If only a few columns can be `NULL` (or only a few combination of columns), then I may have a design.  How many?

Comment: I estimate that perhaps 10-20% of the database at maximum is duplicated.  It could be more though.

There are approx 23 columns in the table of varying types, most of which can have a NULL value, including a bunch of VARCHAR(2)s that hold "Y" "N" or NULL and that's causing issues.  The NULLs have meaning and need to be taken into account when detecting dupes.

Comment: The following query has proven to work, but it's been running for more than 48 hours.. there has to be a faster way:

     
    DELETE a FROM t1_test as a, t1_test as b WHERE
    (a.provnum=b.provnum)
    AND (a.field1=b.field1 OR (a.field1 IS NULL AND b.field1 IS NULL))
    [20 other columns]
    AND (a.recno>b.recno);

Comment: I have several large tables I have to run this on.

Comment: Use `a.field1 <=> b.field1` so you don't have to do extra NULL checks.  [_Reference_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I used that worked..  I ended up having to re-create the table and rename it, but the process time for this was about 90 minutes for a database of 3.1GB and 42 Million records (with about 977,000 dupes):

```
drop table if exists tmp;
create table tmp AS
select distinct field1, field2, field3, ...
 from mytable;
-- add back my rowid
ALTER TABLE `tmp` ADD `recno` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT 
-- add any indexes you were using

-- rename tables
rename table mytable to table_hold;
rename table tmp to mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this?

```
create table tmp as
    select distinct t.*
    from mytable t;
```

EDIT:

If you want all the fields with the minimum of the first:

```
create table tmp as
    select min(id), field1, field2, . . .
    from mytable t
    group by field1, field2, . . .
```

Comment: I also have an auto increment field that needs to be ignored.

Comment: @TrentThree . . . Then don't use `*`, list all the columns you care about.

Comment: Is there any way to preserve the recno A.I. column?

Comment: @TrentThree  . . . You can use `min()`.

Comment: min() doesn't seem to work inside the select query - not sure how to mix distinct and non-distinct columns in the query..

Comment: your query resulted in only pulling 1 row from the original table.. didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can select them with a query like:

```
  SELECT field1, field2, field3, count(1)
    FROM t
GROUP BY field1, field2, field3
  HAVING count(1) > 1
```

And then delete them with code or use some kind of control logic, whatever is available in in mysql.  I'm sure there are other ways to do it.

Comment: I need a mysql/mariadb specific solution.  I'm not sure exactly what you're suggesting.

Comment: @TrentThree, that syntax works for MySql and MariaDb.

Comment: Can you add the additional control logic?  I'm unsure how that would work... the query above simply shows the dupe records?

assuming i have a rowid column called "recno", could I use that in some sort of delete from table where recno=(select rowid ....)  ?

Comment: Also, wouldn't a GROUP BY be a very time-intensive query on a table with 40+ million records?

Comment: Don't know about the time, you'd have to test it.  Group By works, I don't know the theory but I'm sure mysql has figured it out.  As to the control logic, I was thinking of using cursors or T-SQL or C or Java to delete the results of the query.  I don't know what's available in mysql.  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Oooo, that was a challenge.

```
CREATE TABLE _t LIKE real;
INSERT INTO _t
    SELECT MIN(recno),   -- or MAX, if you prefer
           a,b,c,...,w   -- all the other columns
        FROM real
        GROUP BY
           a,b,c,...,w,
           ((a IS NULL) << 0) |
           ((b IS NULL) << 1) |
           ...
           ((w IS NULL) << 22) ;
-- Note: This will not work for more than 64 columns.

-- Put it in place (with no downtime):
RENAME TABLE real TO old, _t TO real;
DROP TABLE old;
```